# Warning during google places api implementation (Flutter)

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-places-api, flutter-dependencies

So I am trying to add the Google Places API inside the code of my application, but I am getting these errors:

```
        E/flutter (18565): #4      _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1122:38)
        E/flutter (18565): #5      _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
        E/flutter (18565): #6      _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
        E/flutter (18565): #7      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
        E/flutter (18565): #8      _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
        E/flutter (18565): #9      _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
        E/flutter (18565): #10     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:949:23)
        E/flutter (18565): #11     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
        E/flutter (18565): #12     _Timer._runTimers  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:384:19)
        E/flutter (18565): #13     _Timer._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)
        E/flutter (18565): #14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
```

Some of my code:

```
    Future<void> fetchAddress() async {
        Prediction prediction = 
        await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
            context: context,
            onError: onError,
            apiKey: 'dummy',
            mode: Mode.fullscreen, // Mode.overlay
            language: "en");
        setState(() {
          selectedAddress1 = prediction.description;
        });
      }
```

Comment: What dependencies are you using? Does your API key have restrictions?

Comment: I am using 
flutter_google_places: ^0.2.6
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.17